# Find xls files created by excel macro in a folder

Tags: vba, excel, csv

The macro that I intend to write must process given csv files in a folder followed by conversion to xls format.

Then I want to find all the created xls files in the same folder and merge them into one xlsx file.

The first loop runs fine (to find all csv files in the folder, process them and convert them into xls format).

However, when I try to find all the xls files, it returns empty. I also tried to debug and add watches. It returns empty string.

I am not sure what is wrong in my code. Please see below.

```
    Sub Macro2()

    fname = "Consolidated  Excel Spreadsheet" & ".xlsx"
    fpath = "C:\Path\"
    StrDstFile = fpath & fname
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs StrDstFile, FileFormat:=51
    Set DstWb = ActiveWorkbook
    CsvFile = Dir(fpath & "*.csv")
    ' This runs absolutely fine.
    Do While CsvFile <> ""
        StrSrcFile = fpath & CsvFile
        Set SrcWb = Workbooks.Open(StrSrcFile)
        SrcWb.Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(SrcWb.FullName, ".csv", ".xls"), FileFormat:=xlExcel8
        SrcWb.Close True
        Set SrcWb = Nothing
        CsvFile = Dir
    Loop
    XlsFile = Dir(fpath & ".xls")
    ' This does not find any xls files in the directory, even though the files exist here
    Do While XlsFile <> ""
        StrSrcFile = fpath & XlsFile
        Set SrcWb = Workbooks.Open(StrSrcFile)
        SrcWb.Activate
        XlsFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `*` in `XlsFile = Dir(fpath & ".xls")`

It should be `XlsFile = Dir(fpath & "*.xls")`

Comment: Glad I could help! Please take a minute to accept answer and take the tour to discover how SO works : http://stackoverflow.com/tour